# Windows 7 change between desktop search providers

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, google-desktop-search

I'm using Google desktop search on windows 7 but wanted to swap back to windows search (as it will allow the searching of mm files - mind maps).

I've stopped the desktop service and started the 'Windows Search' service when I search in the start menu, it brings up a 404 error in the browswer as it's still running google's desktop search. Does anyone know how I can swap between search providers?

Thanks, 
Richard

Answer (score 4):

Start --> DefaultPrograms --> Set your default programs --> Windows Search Explorer --> Set this program as default

:)

Answer (score 3):

The google desktop search does not disable the Windows desktop search.  It sounds like you're using the google desktop "client" to search through the Windows Desktop Search indexes.  This is not possible.  There should be a separate widget/tool for the "Windows Desktop Search" which you may need to add in place of the google-desktop search.